# Is it possible to to return an HTML file as a response in WireMock?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, wiremock

I am trying to return HTML file as a response in wire mock. Is it possible and how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

1. If you're running standalone, create the HTML file and put it under the `__files` directory. The URL path will be the relative path to the file, so e.g. `__files/myfolder/mypage.html` will be served at `http://localhost:8080/myfolder/mypage.html`.
2. Create a stub with a `Content-Type` response header of `text/html; charset=utf-8` and the HTML in the response body.